# jQuery UI tabs. Reload active tab in non-ajax tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Loading/Selecting a (non-ajax) tab from within one of the other tabs can be done by using

```
$('#mytabscontainer').tabs('select', 3)
```

However, I need to be able to reload the active tab, and above method does not work for that. Neither does

```
$('#mytabcontainer').tabs('load', 3)
```

Any ideas on how to achive this?

---

**
**Solution**
**

In the jQuery 'tabs' plugin, replace the line containing:

```
if (($li.hasClass('ui-tabs-selected') && !o.collapsible) ||
```

with

```
if (
```

And add a css to the page / or edit the jQuery css files, so that you get:

```
div.ui-tabs ul li.ui-tabs-selected a {cursor: pointer !important;}
```

This will change tabs so that they're always selecteable, even if they've previously been clicked upon.

Comment: Why would you need to reload the content of a non-ajax tab? The load method applies only to ajax tabs FYI.

Comment: Well, in one of the tabs there's a list of items. There's also a link to add an item to the list. I want to refresh the list after adding the new link. Seems easier than dynamically adding the new item to the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this html for your tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Ajax Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Ajax Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

With tab 1 being the non-ajax tab. That tab doesn't have a url that it can refresh from.  So you first need to give it a url before you can reload it:

```
var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
tabs.tabs( 'url', 0,'ajax/content0.html');
tabs.tabs('load', 0);
```

Remember that the tabs are zero-indexed.

Comment: What if I don't want the original tab to be remotely loaded? Also see my comment below the first comment on my post.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make it so that the script that adds the new item send back the list so you can refresh the html with it.

Comment: Which amounts to refreshing the tab. But I guess that's not possible.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that'd be a sollution. How about when I have this:

| tab1 | tab2 | tab3 |

Click on tab2 will show a list ('list') of links. Clicking on one of the links in the list will remove the list, and show a bunch of stuff ('content') related to the clicked item. Now, when I'm done reading 'content', I want to show 'list' again. I could do that by including some element in 'content' that, when clicked, removes 'content' and reenables 'list'. I think it would be more natural to just reanable the link in the tab, and have the user click the tab *again*.

(hmm, no formatting in comments?)

Answer (score 2):

if your tab's html is like this....

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">NON AJAX TAB</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        NON AJAX CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

and if the page that this occurs on is, say, "page.html"

```
$("#tabs-1").load("page.html #tabs-1");
```

should do the trick

Comment: also note: If [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, as is the case here, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the content of the tab that was clicked and reload it with the same content (or anything you want). For instance:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({                                                                  
  activate:function(event,ui){ 
    //Remove the content of the current tab
    ui.newPanel.empty();
    //load the file you want into current panel
    ui.newPanel.load('content'+(ui.newTab.index()+1)+'.php');                                                 
  }                                                                          
});
```

In this case, for example if the second tab is clicked, the panel is emptied and reloaded with content2.php